# Keydown event for editable datagrid flash

Tags: apache-flex, events, datagrid, keydown

Hi All i have a flex editable datagrid. By default if i press the left navigation arrow key , it moves to the left but not to the next cell. I would like to override the keydown event such that if the left navigation arrow key is pressed down i set the focus to the next cell on the left.

In short the user needs to be able to  navigate using the keyboard through the cells using just like in excel(currently the arrow keys move between characters within a cell).

Comment: Such a move would break "UI Precedence" and may confuse users.  When editing a text input; the arrow keys should not move to the next column.

Comment: i understand but its a requirement i cant run away from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't get away from this requirement.  I'd try adding an event listener to the [KEY_UP](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#KEY_UP) event.  If it is a charCode for an arrow key, destroy the [itemEditor with the destroyItemEditor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#destroyItemEditor%28%29) method and manually move to the next column by setting the [editedItemPosition](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#editedItemPosition) property.

I'm pretty sure charCode 39 is the right arrow and charCode 37 if the left, at least according to [this app](http://www.bensilvis.com/?p=146) .

Comment: Thank you so much am getting there now, how can i get the rowindex and columnindex am on ?I tested with the following.


 protected function dataGrid_keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
 {
  if(event.keyCode == 39){
   event.preventDefault();     
   dataGrid.editedItemPosition ={columnIndex:1, rowIndex:0}
  }
  
 }

Comment: Try looking at the editedItemPosition before you change it.  Since it is not a "write only" property, you should get the current position.